# GTK SourceView scroll to mark not working

Tags: gtk3, pygobject, gtksourceview

I'm trying to fill a SourceView's buffer with text and then scroll to make a specific line visible, like this:

```
lines = '....'.split('\n')
line_number = 76 # For instance, assuming lines has at least this many lines
buffer = view.get_buffer()
for line in lines:
  buffer.insert(end_iter, line + '\n')
iter = buffer.get_iter_at_line()
mark = buffer.get_mark('insert')
buffer.move_mark(mark, iter)
mark = buffer.get_mark('selection_bound')
buffer.move_mark(mark, iter)
view.scroll_to_mark(mark, 0.3, True, 0, 0.5)
```

This scrolls to more-or-less random places in the buffer.  Is there something I'm doing wrong here?  Or does this just not work?

Comment: I am not sure about `scroll_to_mark`, but `scroll_to_iter` works for me.

Comment: `scroll_to_iter` doesn't work for me.  I believe this is because I am calling it immediately after filling the text buffer, and `scroll_to_iter` relies on calculated line heights which are calculated in an idle handler.  This is described in the documentation for `scroll_to_iter`, which suggests using `scroll_to_mark` to "avoid oddness".  I just get a different type of oddness.

Comment: You have applied tags `pygtk`, `gtk3`, and `pyobject`. These are not compatible. Either it is pygtk and gtk2, or then gtk3 and pyobject. Please fix for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, `scroll_to_iter` depends on the idle recalculate. For that matter, `scroll_to_mark`  does too. This works for me:

```
from gi.repository import GLib
#........ code here
GLib.idle_add(view.scroll_to_mark, mark, 0.1, True, 0.0, 0.5)
```

Comment: This seems a little strange, as gtksourceview-3 and introspection + GLib require an extra parameter - priority. Even providing that parameter as `GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT_IDLE`, this trick (`idle_add`) does not work.